# Cannot add qt version to qt visual studio plugin

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2019, qt-vs-addin

I'm using Visual studio 2019 and I've added the Qt Visual Studio Tools plugin from the "Manage Extensions" window. I've installed the latest version 2.7.2.2.

When I try to add a Qt version, in Options->Qt->Versions, I'm able to add the Qt that I've installed (that I use with CMake etc, so I know that's working), and I save it.

[image]

When I save, close and reopen the same window, the version disappears, like the plugin is not able to save the configuration.

I'm not able to find any logs that tell me what did wrong, so:

- Where can I find logs for checking the error when trying to add the Qt version?
- Where the configuration should be stored?

If I know where the data are stored, I can try to add the configuration manually instead of using the GUI, hoping that it will fix the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS2019 not saving qtversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70341066/vs2019-not-saving-qtversion)

Answer (score 1):

i came across the same error. Then if you look at the 'output' of VS when you click ok after setting the QT version, you may see the same error message saying that qt license is not found.  Try download the license file from QT, rename it as .qt-license, and put it under c:/Users//

Comment: This worked. In my case I had intentionally deleted the "C:\Qt\Qt{version}\Licenses".
When they add "features" like this it just adds pain for the users.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms and the reason was an incomplete installation of Qt. I had unzipped the Qt directory from a ZIP archive and that had apparently broken without error message, so files were missing. Unpacking again with 7-Zip fixed the problem.