# VS2019 not saving qtversion

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2019

VS2019
Qt 5.12.11

In VS2019 tools/options/qt/versions, I add the path to qt. Close the window, reopen it, the path is gone.

I had older versions of Qt on the system. They are now gone.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps VS2019 lacks or lost permissions to update the config file where this would be saved, or your config file somehow got corrupted. Are other settings changes persisted in general for VS2019, or is it localized to Qt settings?

Comment: I've redownloaded Qt using from the Qt site, using the binaries. Still the same problem.  I don't think it is a permissions issue. I have admin privileges and everything else gets saved. I found other people complaining about a similar problem a couple of years ago with an older version of Qt. They concluded it was a Qt bug and their solution was to go back to an older version of Qt. One would have thought that Qt would have fixed the bug by now.

Comment: If anyone from the Qt company is out there, how about checking for errors and reporting them, rather than just not saving the data.

Comment: OK. This is getting weird. If I put in an invalid path, I get an error and the path is saved. If I put in the valid path, it disappears without an error.

Comment: Anyone know what should be in that path field? For some reason, I am trying to put in the path of cmake.exe (as installed by the Qt installer). Not sure why I concluded that was the proper path. Can't find any documentation on it. Of course, it would be nice if the installation actually did the entire installation

Comment: == Qt Visual Studio Tools version 2.7.2 (rev.2)

   Initialized in: 666.45 msecs
   Main (UI) thread: 346.82 msecs

Exception "The system cannot find the file specified":
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at QtVsTools.Core.QMake.Run(Boolean setVCVars)
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1

Comment: So, I no longer know what the hell I have. I used the Qt installer from their website. I believe that it has downloaded Qt6 binaries. Doesn't appear to have downloaded any sources. The sources on their website are some release of version 5. None of which makes any sense.

Comment: Can someone who has installed Qt before, explain how this is all supposed to work? Clearly the binaries installation from Qt doesn't do everything that is needed, and they don't have instructions on how to do the rest. Does the Qt binaries installation work? It looks like most people just download the sources and do their own build of the binaries. This strikes me as opening a can of worms. I'm trying to install Qt on my personal laptop which isn't really set up for development. I don't have perl installed, or git.

Comment: If you suspect it's a bug (sounds like it may be) then you're better off filing a bug report and/or looking through active bugs than posting comments to Qt about it here, here's Qt's bug reporting system: https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: I'm having the same issue with VS2022 Community. Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but was able to fix it via this link [Qt VS Tools: error reading VS project settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61942091/qt-vs-tools-error-reading-vs-project-settings).

Basically, you need to make sure you have the MSVC version of Qt instead of MinGW, because Visual Studio is only compatible with the MSVC version.